# how to fix the application response error in heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-cli

now I'm trying to upload my project on Heroku cloud and the website has uploaded successfully but I get the application error page from heroku when I try to enter the page the files I have created are:

- Pipfile
- Pipfile.lock
- Procfile
- pyvenv.cfg
- requirements.txt

and I did everything the heroku needs it so, what's going on here?

procfile

```
web: gunicorn website.wsgi
```

please tell me How can I fix that error and get the response page!

**Edit post:**

```
2020-08-09T11:44:17.624839+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-09T11:44:25.491114+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website.wsgi`
2020-08-09T11:44:28.774370+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-09 11:44:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-08-09T11:44:28.774934+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-09 11:44:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:24097 (4)
2020-08-09T11:44:28.775043+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-09 11:44:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-08-09T11:44:28.778601+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-09 11:44:28 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2020-08-09T11:44:28.835957+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-09 11:44:28 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915918+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-09 11:44:29 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915974+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915976+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915976+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915977+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915977+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915977+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915978+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915978+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915978+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915979+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915979+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915979+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915980+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915980+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915980+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915981+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915982+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915982+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915982+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915983+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915983+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915983+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915984+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915984+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/website/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915984+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915985+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915985+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915985+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915986+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915986+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915986+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915987+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915987+00:00 app[web.1]: module = import_module(entry)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915987+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915988+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915988+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915988+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915989+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-08-09T11:44:29.915989+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'
2020-08-09T11:44:29.916079+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-09 11:44:29 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917005+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-09 11:44:29 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917006+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917007+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917007+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917008+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917008+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917008+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917009+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917009+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917009+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917010+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917010+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917010+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917011+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917017+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917017+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917018+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917018+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917018+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917019+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917019+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917020+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917020+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917020+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917021+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/website/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917021+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917021+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917021+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917022+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917022+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917022+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917023+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917023+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917023+00:00 app[web.1]: module = import_module(entry)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917024+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917024+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917024+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917025+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917025+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917026+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'
2020-08-09T11:44:29.917231+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-09 11:44:29 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2020-08-09T11:44:30.090768+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-09 11:44:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-08-09T11:44:30.090842+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-09 11:44:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-08-09T11:44:30.159057+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-08-09T11:44:30.200613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-09T11:44:37.183618+00:00 heroku[run.2557]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2020-08-09T11:44:37.709576+00:00 heroku[run.2557]: Process exited with status 129
2020-08-09T11:44:37.749575+00:00 heroku[run.2557]: State changed from up to complete
2020-08-09T11:45:33.686015+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by user medoabdin@gmail.com
2020-08-09T11:45:45.469923+00:00 heroku[run.5007]: State changed from starting to up
2020-08-09T11:45:45.751097+00:00 heroku[run.5007]: Awaiting client
2020-08-09T11:45:45.811639+00:00 heroku[run.5007]: Starting process with command `bash`
```

Comment: Are you using django-allauth?

Answer (score 0):

The `Procfile` format should be:

```
web: gunicorn ProjectName.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

Make sure you have added your application in installed app of `settings.py`

If you are using `django-allauth` make sure you have added it to your `requirements.txt`

Comment: ok, but for application which applications I have to add? I have more than one

Comment: please check here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration

Comment: now the document is using (web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi) only and that what I typed in my question and that defines that I should no write app so, what is a mistake I made

Comment: I edited the post please check on it but knowing that among errors you will see: (no module named allauth) but I did install indeed

Comment: Have you added your app in settings.py "installed app"?

Comment: I add both of: (allauth, allauth.account, 'allauth.socialaccount', 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook' and 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google')

Comment: and that works fine in localhost I have no errors in localhost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219491/discussion-between-abdelhamed-abdin-and-tasnuva).

Comment: Use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` then push again to heroku.

Comment: I chatting you in chat could you following with me please